# How to redirect requests to another folder using .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, redirects

How to redirect requests to another folder using *.htaccess*?

I have my root directory and my website looks into that directory. I want it to look in the `/subdirectory/` instead. I can't modify the server config.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ subdirectory [L]
```

If you want an external redirect, set the `R` flag there as well:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /subdirectory [L,R=301]
```

Comment: OK, it redirects, but I see  www.myurl.com/subdirectory
how can I hide `subdirectory` from URL?

Comment: Check this answer out http://stackoverflow.com/a/10427485/804087